# Reponsive text size in css

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, fullscreen

I am developing a simple website using a table (100% width). This website will be viewed on a 30" and 47"  tv, so my text within the table will need to adapt to the screen sizes. Should I apply a 100% on the font size? or perhaps another method?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Read over [this font sizes article](http://kyleschaeffer.com/user-experience/css-font-size-em-vs-px-vs-pt-vs/) to get a good idea about "responsive" typography.

Answer (score 3):

I would look into media queries.

http://mediaqueri.es/

http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into using [Responsive-Measure](https://github.com/jbrewer/Responsive-Measure).

**"A jQuery plugin for generating a responsive ideal measure."**

Basically it enlarges the font to match the width of its parent dom item. Which would be nice if you are sitting a distance from the TV.

Answer (score 0):

I guess [this](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/handling-typography-responsive-design) tutorial will help you.

You can also find few links at the bottom of the tutorial that will provide you with additional insights..